# POST data with diffrent character set

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I use grails to receive data by POST from a few external resources. My gails controller works great as long as the character set of the posted data is UTF-8.

Unfortunately I also have external sources posting data to the grails controller using character set of 8859-1 and the result is that the åäö for example cannot be processed correctly.

How can I use grails to also being able to receive POST data of different character sets, in my case utf-8 and 8859-1?

I have different controllers and actions for each external source sending data.

Thanks Karolina

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ISO-8859-1 just cannot encode these characters, and the first 256 codes in UTF-8 are the same as those for ISO-8859-1 (so if it could, UTF-8 would also succeed)

So the problem is not at your end, and you can't fix it.

Comment: Actually, only first 128 codes of utf-8 is the same as those in iso-8859-1, so utf-8 is superset of ascii.

Comment: It is a superset by all means, that's what i said

Answer (score 0):

You cant reliably solve this problem solely on server side, because at the time when you received decoded strings in your grails controller, they were already decoded by servlet container assuming byte stream was in default charset(utf-8) and CharsetDecoder already replaced invalid byte sequences with ?. That means you cant reliably get original bytes back from decoded strings to re-decode them using some other charset (iso-8859-1).

You can solve this on http client side by specifying charset in content type header when posting:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Another option is to post mutipart data, then servlet container of grails app wont decode bytes to string and you'll have to manually decode them to string using any charset you want.